# Muslim male to marry a non Muslim female

Tags: nikah

I have been with my partner for quite some time and we have had the conversation of marriage for a while. 
We have overcome some big hurdles already but now we are looking at getting married and are not too sure what to expect.

I am looking at converting but do not yet feel ready to do so.

My main question is can we have a Nikah without me converting with the intention of doing so in the near future?

I am generally looking for some advise in what to expect.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A Muslim male can only marry either a Muslim or a Kitabee (Jew or Christian). If the female is not either of these religions then it is not permissible to marry her, even if she may have an intention to convert later.

Comment: Salam and welcome IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your question as @UmH pointed out these kinds of question have answers. But to answer them properly we need a bit more information:1) I guess you are female, is your partner a Muslim (man)? (than the cases should be answered in the linked post) 2) Else please add additional information because based on your belief(s) your relationship (so far) the situation may vary a Muslim can only marry a Muslim or a chaste girl from the people of the book.